# Find the number of zeros of a complex function using Rouche's theorem: Review my work

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = e^z +1 - 4z^n$
How many zeros does $f$ have inside $|z|<1$?

My Work:

For $|z|=1$, we have that:
$$
|g(z)|=|e^z+1|\\
\leq e^{|z|}+1\\
=e+1\\
<4\\
=|-4z^n|\\
=|h(z)|
$$

Thus, $f=g+h$ has the same number of zeros as $h(z)$, which is $n$.

Comment: Can anyone confirm my work?

Comment: Your approach and answer are correct.

Comment: @MartinR I am working on the boundary of the circle?

Comment: Yes, my fault. I'll delete that comment.